# How to delete the entered number during call

Tags: calls, phone-app

I found no backspace button to edit the number once inserted in keypad during call.

[image: screen-shot of the dialer]

I found this when I called my mobile operator customer care service which uses DMT, and suddenly the customer care executive asked me to tell my Sim Message Center Number which I thought to find by typing `*#*#4636#*#*`.

How to delete the number.

My phone is Nexus 5.

Comment: I'm not in a call currently, so I cannot check: but could it be you can long-press the input (to mark it) and the "cut" it to the clipboard? Worth a try at least. // Apart from that: how are you supposed to "execute" a service-code while in a call? I'm not sure that would even work.

Comment: @Izzy yes I am able to execute service code while in call.

Comment: And does "long-press-and-cut" (as described in my previous comment) work? Plus, as you found a solution: Maybe you post it as answer?

Comment: @Izzy no long press is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a workaround. By clicking new call button, I am able to type new number and execute service codes.

[image: New call button]

Answer (score 7):

Before you place a call there is a backspace symbol to the right of the numbers that you've entered that you can use to delete any of the numbers that you've already entered.

[image: Nexus 5 dialler before placing a call]

However, once you've actually rung a number and started a call, the backspace disappears and you can't delete numbers (as in your screenshot in the question).

The reason for this is that while you're making a call the numbers that you type in are *instantly* transmitted down the phone line as [DTMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling) (or touch-tone) signals so that you can navigate through voicemail menus, phone menu trees (eg "*press 1 for billing, press 2 for complaints...*"), dial extension numbers, etc.

You can't delete a dial tone that's *already* been transmitted. This is the same as while you're in the middle of one phone call you can't just type numbers into the dialler and start a totally different phone call. So the [dialer code](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/dialer-codes/info) that you typed in to try to show your SIM message number wouldn't work because the numbers and symbols would have been transmitted down the phone line as beeps while you typed them (possibly annoying the person on the other end) instead of being used as a "service code" instruction by the phone.

Answer (score 0):

very simple guys.
while you are on call you should close all background apps including call and later reopen the call,and now check your dail pad it will be fresh